# Overlapping divs on absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

There are quite some topics out there about this topic, but none of them solved my issue.

```
<div class="outer"> <!-- fixed height -->
  <div class="inner">content</div> <!-- needs to be placed AFTER outer -->
</div>
<!-- the inner div should be placed here with css AND NOT overlap any of the following content -->
<div>no overlap please</div>
```

`outer` has an exact height while `inner` height depends on its contents. I need to move `inner` *after* the `outer` container; *without* it overlapping the following contents. Since I don't know the height of the `inner` div I can't just use `margin` on the `outer`.

In case of asking: structure has to be like this. It's a bootstrap carousel and I need to put the indicators of the carousel at the bottom - the indicators need to be inside the slider div.

**Edit**: the problem is not HOW to get the `inner` container at the bottom of the the `outer` container. The problem by positioning it absolute and set it to bottom is that the content overlaps upcoming divs.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: So what is your issue ?? What have you tried & it didn't work.

Comment: See edited question.

Answer (score 7):

I can think of the following:

```
.outer {postion:relative;}
.inner {
   position: absolute;
   top: 100%;
}
```

This will display the .inner after .outer. If that's not what you mean however, you might want to try moving the elements with jquery. Just let me know and I will try to help.

EDIT:

If it must be dynamic, I guess you should use javascript, or at least I am not familiar with any other way by CSS. Please see a working example with JQuery in the Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r6hskbn3/3/

Comment: The problem is not how to get the div out of its parent, but overlapping is the issue. See the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set top position to 100% for this

```
.inner {
   position: absolute;
   top: 100%;
}
```